# What happens when we know that there is something that we forgot but we can't remember what it was?

Tags: human-biology, brain

I think it happens for everyone that sometimes we go to a room and forget why we went there. Is there any research or article on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a phenomenon known as room amnesia, some research has shown that your brain may use physical barriers like the room and doorways as a way to compartmentalize thoughts.
One article summarizes it [here](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode.cfm?id=doorway-to-blame-for-room-amnesia-11-11-30):

> The researchers say that when you pass through a doorway, your mind
>   compartmentalizes your actions into separate episodes. Having moved
>   into a new episode, the brain archives the previous one, making it
>   less available for access. It’s as if you slam a mental door between
>   what you knew and…what was I saying?

[This is the research.](http://www.nd.edu/~memory/Reprints/Radvansky%20Krawietz%20&%20Tamplin%202011%20%28QJEP%29.pdf)

Comment: Nice! I wonder if this works with transparent walls. Perhaps Japanese style semi-transparent paper walls?

Comment: Try it! Go to your local garden centre, stand in a display greenhouse, think of something to go and buy, then walk out of the greenhouse and see if you remember!

Comment: Thanks for the concise yet comprehensive answer.